# Encryption & decryption with PGP

Tags: gpg, openpgp

I want to be able to encrypt and decrypt a simple file.

- I followed [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GnuPrivacyGuardHowto) to generating an OpenPGP Key, it `gets stuck` at this step `You will be asked to tap on the keyboard (or do any of the things you normally do) in order for randomization to take place.`
- And are these the right commands to encrypt and decrypt the file ?

`alice% gpg --output doc.gpg --encrypt --recipient`

`blake% gpg --output doc --decrypt doc.gpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generation of new OpenPGP key pairs with GnuPG requires quite a lot of entropy, and thus key generation can take some time. Do some work while waiting to help the kernel provide more random bits, in case of virtual machines which often suffer from low entropy consider using software like `haveged`.

The commands seem reasonable apart that `--recipient` requires an argument (it is used to define the recipient, provide a key ID or mail address). Generally, GnuPG should always have options precede commands -- the difference is not always easy to spot (all are prefixed with dashes), but options explain *how* to do something, while commands define what GnuPG should do (encrypt, sign, decrypt, create keys, ...). Finally, you missed providing some input (there are different ways to do so). So your first command should rather read:

```
gpg --output doc.gpg --recipient <key-definition> --encrypt < message.txt
```